# Pass a value to a script in cron

Tags: linux, cron

I'm running a script in cron, and would like to pass a value to the script.

I'm trying to do something like this in crontab:

- - - - - php -q /home/cron/some_script.php?variable=1

Where the variable would be read by $_GET in the script.

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use argv:

```
/path/to/script.php x y z
```

Then, in script.php:

```
print_r($argv);
```

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./script.php
    [1] => x
    [2] => y
    [3] => z
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing a webserver and a shell.

```
/home/cron/some_script.php
```

Is your script. If you want to pass things into it on the command line you would do:

```
/home/cron/some_script.php arg1 arg2
```

And parse the arguments in your script.